# Можно ли присвоить псевдокласс псевдоклассу?

Tags: html, css

Пытаюсь стилизовать элемент, выводимый через :after

```
.again:after:hover
```

Comment: Эта конструкция режется хромовским девтулом

Comment: потому что наоборот надо: .again:hover:after

Comment: Не работает конструкция: .again:hover:after {...}

Comment: приведите пример Вашего кода и поясните, как именно Вы хотите стилизовать элемент, чтобы было понятно, что именно не работает

Comment: Если вы хотите повесить `:hover` только на `:after`, то нельзя.

Answer (score 5):

Вот Вам пример того, как эта конструкция работает:

```css
.again {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}

.again:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  right: -35px;
}

.again:hover:after {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="again"></div>
```